# Manually enter a Windows path in Bash, how to convert to a POSIX path?

Tags: windows, bash, sh, git-bash

When I manually enter the Windows path in Bash,
I want to convert it to a POSIX path and save it in a variable.
But escape characters are not escaped.

I want to type `C:\Users\xiang\Downloads\Compressed` and convert it to
`/c/users/xiang/downloads/compressed`

```sh
#!/bin/sh

read -rp "Enter a path: " pth

dir=$(echo "/$pth" | sed -e 's/\\/\//g' -e 's/://')

cd ${dir}

git status

read -n 1 -s -r -p "Press any key to continue"

exit 0;
```

[image]

Comment: use `read -r`. Check the man page for details.

Comment: Looks like git bash packages the `cygpath` executable which was created for Cygwin to do exactly what you require, so I suggest using it instead : `cygpath 'C:\foo'` outputs `/c/foo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the backslashes in your Windows route are considered as a way to escape a character.

Here you have two options, either you write the route with double backslashes (C:\\Users\\...) or you can use `read -rp "Enter a path: " pth` (note the r).

Personally I prefer the second option, as you don't have to tell other users to write the route with double backslashes, and is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

It is because bash is considering the backslash `\` in your `C:\Users\<user>\Downloads\Compressed` as an escape character. To solve this issue you need to give the input as `C:\\Users\\<user>\\Downloads\\Compressed`.